# Set Page Width of PDF

Tags: export, output-formatting, pdf-format

I have a very simple question. I am using the student version of Mathematica 9, and I often do my homework in it. I type up a notebook, and then save it as a PDF using the "save as" option. However, the resulting PDF's word wrapping freaks out, and I often get lines of printed text that only go about halfway across the page before jumping to the next line.

I just want to be able set my page width to match an ordinary 8.5"-11" document for the whole notebook so that is displays correctly as a PDF. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your File->Printing Settings->Page Setup as you want it.

Set Format->Screen Environment to PrintOut.

Most people (assumptions are risky) aren't printing out every notebook so the normal environment is much less cramped than PrintOut.